# Qt OpenGL transform feedback buffer functions missing

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, transform-feedback

I've been following a [tutorial series](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html) for learning OpenGL, and the [current tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial28/tutorial28.html) I'm trying to do involves creating particle systems using the OpenGL transform feedback buffer.

In my application I've been using Qt version 5.4.2 for simple 2D interface design, as well as for 3D rendering since it seems to have a plethora of classes for working with OpenGL.

Everything was going smoothly up to this point, but despite having access to OpenGL functions up to version 4.3, I still seem to be missing functions for using the **Transform Feedback buffer**, which according to the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback) have been core functions since version 3.0.

I have done some quick research and found old news items and blog posts back in 2012 about possibly supporting such features in the future, however I can't find anything relevant since then.

In the past I've also seen people figure out some ways to access other functions that the Qt wrappers haven't directly implemented, but I'm unsure of how to do this on my own.

### So, in a nutshell, **How can I make use of the OpenGL transform feedback buffer and other similar functions in Qt 5.4.2?**

I would really hate to get stuck at a point like this because the wrapper isn't finished.

In the off-chance I'm simply missing a header inclusion, I've tried including the following but the functions I'm after are still undefined:

```
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core>
#include <QtOpenGLExtensions/QOpenGLExtensions>
#include <QtOpenGLDepends>
#include <QtOpenGL/qgl.h>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
```

Comment: Simply grep for the functions in Qt's headers. If they're missing, file a qt bug.

Comment: Thanks, I searched through the headers and realized I wasn't actually extending the right class all along.

Comment: Please see QOpenGLExtraFunctions Class. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglextrafunctions.html#details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I never actually extended my class to use QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core, and it was instead just QOpenGLFunctions. 
Changing it to the former solved the problem.